# shell script executes as root when it should execute as current logged in user

Tags: bash, shell, root, macos-sierra

I was logged in via SSH as the user who was currently logged in.

I enter the remote computer using my admin account.

```
ssh admin_a@ipaddress
```

Then proceeded with:

```
su username_b (current login user)
```

The result left me in bash-prompt (which I don't understand) as the current user logged in ( tested this by using `whoami` ).

**Q1**: When I switch over to the user who is logged in, why does it put me into bash-prompt (i.e. `~bash$` ) - why not `~ username_of_current_user$` ?

After I created the bash script and placed it into the current user's directory - the script is called from launch agents, although it doesn't work.

The error logs showed that one of the variable's output is wrong: `whoami = root`, when it should = `current_user_logged_in`.

Q2: Why is the script being called from root?

Comment: Try `su - username_b` or `su -l username_b` (they are the same) to emulate a full login as `username_b` user. The environment is minimally modified by `su username_b`.

Answer (score 1):

`su -` invokes a login shell after switching the user. A login shell resets most environment variables, providing a clean base.

`su` just switches the user, providing a normal shell with an environment nearly the same as with the old user.

The most obvious example of this is that `~` is root's home directory if you use `su -`, but your own home directory if you use `su`.

Depending on your system, it may also mean differences in `prompt`, `PATH`, or `history file`.

For more details:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su